# pip install --user xmlstarlet fails on Fedora 37

Tags: linux, python, fedora, pip

I was in the process of refreshing my system with a new install of Fedora 37 (up from 36).  All went well and I started the install of the packages I use.  That went well until I tried to install XMLSTARLET using pip.  Crazy output of that command shown here:

```
  Collecting xmlstarlet
  Downloading xmlstarlet-1.6.8.tar.gz (715 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 715.3/715.3 kB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │    exit code: 2
  ╰─> [230 lines of output]
   /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
     warnings.warn(
   fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/trans.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/trans.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   15 out of 15 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_C14N.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   8 out of 8 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_C14N.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_depyx.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   5 out of 5 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_depyx.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_edit.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   22 out of 22 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_edit.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_elem.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   6 out of 6 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_elem.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_escape.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   4 out of 4 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_escape.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_format.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   6 out of 6 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_format.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_ls.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_ls.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_pyx.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_pyx.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_select.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   18 out of 18 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_select.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_trans.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   9 out of 9 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_trans.c.rej
   patching file xmlstarlet/src/xml_validate.c
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
   Apply anyway? [n]
   Skipping patch.
   7 out of 7 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file xmlstarlet/src/xml_validate.c.rej
   Compiling xmlstarlet C sources...
   make  all-am
   make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/pip-install-fe6qmovj/xmlstarlet_c48ea51fb5f3402f9d7bbde3cdb34c0c/xmlstarlet'
     CC       src/trans.o
     CC       src/xml_C14N.o
     CC       src/xml_depyx.o
     CC       src/xml_edit.o
     CC       src/xml_elem.o
     CC       src/xml_escape.o
     CC       src/xml_format.o
     CC       src/xml_ls.o
     CC       src/xml_select.o
     CC       src/xml_pyx.o
     CC       src/xml_validate.o
     CC       src/usage.o
     CC       src/depyx-usage.o
     CC       src/xml_trans.o
     CC       src/c14n-usage.o
     CC       src/escape-usage.o
     CC       src/format-usage.o
     CC       src/edit-usage.o
     CC       src/elem-usage.o
     CC       src/select-usage.o
     CC       src/ls-usage.o
     CC       src/pyx-usage.o
     CC       src/unescape-usage.o
     CC       src/trans-usage.o
     CC       src/validate-usage.o
   src/xml_C14N.c:12:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
      12 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/xml_elem.c:31:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlstring.h: No such file or directory
      31 | #include <libxml/xmlstring.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   In file included from src/trans.c:4:
   src/trans.h:32:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      32 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_C14N.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_elem.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/trans.o] Error 1
   src/pyx-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/trans-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/pyx-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/usage.o] Error 1
   src/c14n-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/edit-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/select-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/ls-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/c14n-usage.o] Error 1
   src/format-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/edit-usage.o] Error 1
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/select-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/format-usage.o] Error 1
   src/xml_pyx.c:19:10: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
      19 | #include <libxml/parser.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/elem-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/trans-usage.o] Error 1
   src/xml_depyx.c:33:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      33 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/ls-usage.o] Error 1
   src/unescape-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_pyx.o] Error 1
   src/validate-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/elem-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_depyx.o] Error 1
   src/depyx-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/xml_edit.c:35:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      35 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/unescape-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/validate-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_edit.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/depyx-usage.o] Error 1
   In file included from src/xml_trans.c:35:
   src/xmlstar.h:15:10: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
      15 | #include <libxml/xpath.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   In file included from src/xml_validate.c:35:
   src/xmlstar.h:15:10: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
      15 | #include <libxml/xpath.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_trans.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_validate.o] Error 1
   src/escape-usage.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
       2 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/xml_escape.c:36:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      36 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   src/xml_select.c:38:10: fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
      38 | #include <libxml/tree.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/escape-usage.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_select.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_escape.o] Error 1
   src/xml_format.c:35:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      35 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_format.o] Error 1
   src/xml_ls.c:40:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
      40 | #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:936: src/xml_ls.o] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pip-install-fe6qmovj/xmlstarlet_c48ea51fb5f3402f9d7bbde3cdb34c0c/xmlstarlet'
   make: *** [Makefile:718: all] Error 2
   [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
 hint: See above for details.
  
     $ python --version
     Python 3.11.1pip --version
     $ pip 22.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
     $ pip install --upgrade --user setuptools
     Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (65.6.3) 
dnf list xmlstarlet libxslt
Installed Packages
libxslt.x86_64              1.1.37-1.fc37                                                                                                    
xmlstarlet.x86_64           1.6.1-20.fc37
```

I did some research and can't find this problem anywhere else.  I tried  reinstalling in a VM but that did not resolve it.  I tried upgrading what I could find and I still get the same errors.  I am assuming one simple problem triggering all this but I cannot figure it out. My question is what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [pypi project page for xmlstarlet](https://pypi.org/project/xmlstarlet/#files), you can see that there are binary releases up to python 3.10 (`cp310`). There is no binary release for python's latest release, 3.11, which fedora 37 now uses.

Pip tries to build the package from source, but fails. The immediate reason seems to be that you're missing libxml development files (most likely in `libxml2-devel`), but the changelog for xmlstarlet stops at support for python 3.10, and looking at the first few lines of output, I'm not sure it's correctly packaged for source builds (but I could be wrong).

You might need to wait for the xmlstarlet package maintainer to support python 3.11, or patch the project yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I will wait.  I am trying a workaround, using os.system and calling the command-line version of xmlstarlet.  Hopefully it will work and can revert back when the python package catches up.